# Is there any svn command to add a folder directly into repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I need an equivalent command to create a folder in the repository browser on the repository.i.e In the repo browser i can right click and select option `Create folder..`

I don't want to create a folder in the working copy then `add command` and `commit command`.

Is there any command to like `svn add http://remote/tags`. 
Where `tags` is new folder i am trying to create on the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this subcommand is called `mkdir`:

> `$ svn help mkdir`
>
> `mkdir`: Create a new directory under version control.
>
> ```
> usage: 1. mkdir PATH...
>        2. mkdir URL...
> ```
>
> Create version controlled directories.
>
> 1. Each directory specified by a working copy PATH is created locally
>      and scheduled for addition upon the next commit.
> 2. Each directory specified by a URL is created in the repository via
>      an immediate commit.
>
>    In both cases, all the intermediate directories must already exist,
>      unless the `--parents` option is given.

That is, you need that

> Each directory specified by a URL is created in the repository via an immediate commit.

bit.